# processing network packets in spark in a stateful manner

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I would like to use Spark to parse network messages and group them into logical entities in a stateful manner.

*Problem Description*

Let's assume each message is in one row of an input dataframe, depicted below.

```
| row   | time | raw payload   |
+-------+------+---------------+
|  1    | 10   | TEXT1;        |
|  2    | 20   | TEXT2;TEXT3;  |
|  3    | 30   | LONG-         |
|  4    | 40   | TEXT1;        |
|  5    | 50   | TEXT4;TEXT5;L |
|  6    | 60   | ONG           |
|  7    | 70   | -TEX          |
|  8    | 80   | T2;           |
```

The task is to parse the logical messages in the raw payload, and provide them in a new output dataframe. In the example each logical message in the payload ends with a semicolon (delimiter).

The desired output dataframe could then look as follows:

```
| row   | time | message       |
+-------+------+---------------+
|  1    | 10   | TEXT1;        |
|  2    | 20   | TEXT2;        |
|  3    | 20   | TEXT3;        |
|  4    | 30   | LONG-TEXT1;   |
|  5    | 50   | TEXT4;        |
|  6    | 50   | TEXT5;        |
|  7    | 50   | LONG-TEXT2;   |
```

Note that some messages rows do not yield a new row in the result (e.g. rows 4, 6,7,8), and some yield even multiple rows (e.g. rows 2, 5)

*My questions:*

- is this a use case for UDAF? If so, how for example should i implement the `merge` function? i have no idea what its purpose is.
- since the message ordering matters (i cannot process LONGTEXT-1, LONGTEXT-2 properly without respecting the message order), can i tell spark to parallelize perhaps on a higer level (e.g. per calendar day of messages) but not parallelize within a day (e.g. events at time 50,60,70,80 need to be processed in order).
- follow up question: is it conceivable that the solution will be usable not just in traditional spark, but also in spark structured streaming? Or does the latter require its own kind of stateful processing method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i figured it out in the meantime how to do this with an UDAF.

```
class TagParser extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

  override def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(StructField("value", StringType) :: Nil)

  override def bufferSchema: StructType = StructType(
    StructField("parsed", ArrayType(StringType)) ::
      StructField("rest", StringType)
      :: Nil)

  override def dataType: DataType = ArrayType(StringType)

  override def deterministic: Boolean = true

  override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
    buffer(0) = IndexedSeq[String]()
    buffer(1) = null
  }

  def doParse(str: String, buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {

    buffer(0) = IndexedSeq[String]()

    val prevRest = buffer(1)
    var idx = -1
    val strToParse = if (prevRest != null) prevRest + str else str

    do {
      val oldIdx = idx;
      idx = strToParse.indexOf(';', oldIdx + 1)

      if (idx == -1) {
        buffer(1) = strToParse.substring(oldIdx + 1)
      } else {
        val newlyParsed = strToParse.substring(oldIdx + 1, idx)
        buffer(0) = buffer(0).asInstanceOf[IndexedSeq[String]] :+ newlyParsed
        buffer(1) = null
      }

    } while (idx != -1)
  }

  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {

    if (buffer == null) {
      return
    }

    doParse(input.getAs[String](0), buffer)
  }

  override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = throw new UnsupportedOperationException

  override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = buffer(0)
}
```

Here a demo app the uses the above UDAF to solve the problem from above:

```
case class Packet(time: Int, payload: String)

object TagParserApp extends App {

  val spark, sc = ... // kept out for brevity

  val df = sc.parallelize(List(
    Packet(10, "TEXT1;"),
    Packet(20, "TEXT2;TEXT3;"),
    Packet(30, "LONG-"),
    Packet(40, "TEXT1;"),
    Packet(50, "TEXT4;TEXT5;L"),
    Packet(60, "ONG"),
    Packet(70, "-TEX"),
    Packet(80, "T2;")
  )).toDF()

  val tp = new TagParser
  val window = Window.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
  val df2 = df.withColumn("msg", tp.apply(df.col("payload")).over(window))
  df2.show()
}
```

this yields:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+
|time|      payload|           msg|
+----+-------------+--------------+
|  10|       TEXT1;|       [TEXT1]|
|  20| TEXT2;TEXT3;|[TEXT2, TEXT3]|
|  30|        LONG-|            []|
|  40|       TEXT1;|  [LONG-TEXT1]|
|  50|TEXT4;TEXT5;L|[TEXT4, TEXT5]|
|  60|          ONG|            []|
|  70|         -TEX|            []|
|  80|          T2;|  [LONG-TEXT2]|
+----+-------------+--------------+
```

the main issue for me was to figure out how to actually apply this UDAF, namely using this:

```
df.withColumn("msg", tp.apply(df.col("payload")).over(window))
```

the only thing i need now to figure out are the aspects of parallelization (which i only want to happen where we do not rely on ordering) but that's a separate issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can run arbitrary stateful aggregations on spark streaming by using `mapGroupsWithState` of `flatMapGroupsWithState`. You can find some examples [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/17/arbitrary-stateful-processing-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html). None of those though will guarantee that the processing of the stream will be ordered by event time.

If you need to enforce data ordering, you should try to use [window operations on event time](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time). In that case, you need to run stateless operations instead, but if the number of elements in each window group is small enough, you can use `collectList` for instance and then apply a UDF (where you can manage the state for each window group) on each list.

Comment: thanks Erni for your remarks! but it seems i can use mapGroupsWithState/flatMapGroupsWithState only in structured streaming. wouldn't i need to rewrite it differently for non-streaming mode?

Comment: the reason that i ask about batch mode is that my main use case is processing network capture files (which obviously can be done using batch processing). Processing live traffic would be "nice to have".

Comment: As far as I know, mapGroupsWithState and flatMapGroupsWithState should execute on batch too, but Spark will parallelise the input files as much as possible, and you will have a hard time trying to manage the state with that level of parallelisation. 
I would not go that way.